# Returning the wrong value in basic Java program

Tags: java

I run the following program, and the value returned should be `deltaTemp Result: 300` but I'm getting `deltaTemp Result: 0.0`.  Am I missing something basic here?  I don't get any errors...

```
static double weldPadTemp = 177;
static double meltTemp = 260;

public static void main(String[] args){

    deltaTemp(weldPadTemp, meltTemp);

}

public static double deltaTemp(double weldPadTemp, double meltTemp){
    double deltaT;
    deltaT = ((meltTemp-weldPadTemp+457)*(5/9));

    System.out.println("deltaTemp Result:" + deltaT);

    return deltaT;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(5 / 9)` is an integer division, which results in a zero value. You can use `double` literals instead:

```
deltaT = ((meltTemp - weldPadTemp + 457) * (5.0 / 9.0));
```

Answer (score 4):

5/9 is evaluated to 0 since both operands are int values.

Some examples:

```
int x = 5/9;
System.out.println(x);

double y;
y = 5/9;
System.out.println(y);

//5.0 is a double value so the operation is done in double arithmetics
y = 5.0/9;
System.out.println(y);
```

Outputs:

```
0
0.0
0.5555555555555556
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double deltaTemp(double weldPadTemp, double meltTemp){
    double deltaT;
    deltaT = ((meltTemp-weldPadTemp+457)*(5.0/9));

    System.out.println("deltaTemp Result:" + deltaT);

    return deltaT;

}
```

the aritmetic expression (5/9) returns 0 because both num integer. So you should make one of them float (add .0)

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying by `5/9` as an `int`, whose result is `0`.

Cast your second operand as a `double`.

For instance:

```
deltaT = ((meltTemp-weldPadTemp+457)*((double)5/9));
```

**Output**

```
300.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`5/9` equals `0` because `5` and `9` are integers, then the result is calculated as `int`, too.
This will affect `deltaT` because multiplying any number by 
`0` returns `0`.

To make them `double`, put the `D` suffix after each number.

```
5D / 9D
```